# Проблема с кодировкой в сокете Django?

Tags: django

**Доброго времени суток!**

Сразу бы хотелось принести извинения, если неверно сформулирован заголовок.
Я являюсь новичком в языке python  и его библиотеке Django, а потому прошу простить, если буду местами некорректно формулировать проблему.

И так, перейдем к самой проблеме. При попытке запуска сервера ещё "пустого" проекта, путем выполнения команды python manage.py runserver, консоль возвращает следующую ошибку.

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 14 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until yo
 apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
March 27, 2018 - 23:19:39
Django version 2.0.2, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrappe
 at 0x033DEF18>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in w
apper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.p
", line 143, in inner_run
    ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading, server_cls=self.server_cls)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 163,
in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 66,
n __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "D:\Python\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "D:\Python\lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "D:\Python\lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 6: invalid
continuation byte
```

Я уже читал другие статьи на этом сайте, и нет, беда не в имени учетной записи, и в пути до файла нету символов кириллицы. Я растерян и надеюсь на понимание.

Comment: Имя вашего компьютера в сети русское, да?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо пользователю andreymal!!!
В самом деле мой компьютер имел русские символы в имени. После их удаления всё заработало! Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Ответа нема, только коммент, засим нормальный ответ